# Piece of code generates massive amounts of invisible Data

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a excel file which automatically imports and writes data to (2) different sheets.
To reduce the amount of rows used i put a little piece of code that Copies and pastes my data one cell higher.

However, after a little while (after Nextfree exceeds 10), Excel becomes incredibly slow, using up 100% of a CPU core and after a few attempts i finally get to stop the running scripts. When i save the file i noticed that it grew from 100 KB to 5+ MB.

Opening the file again was very slow, and when it was openened it was responding poorly. I couldn't find any big amounts of data, but after deleting row A to D the workbook was finally responding properly again.

I'm wondering what huge of amounts of data this little piece of code is generating and where i can find the data.

```
Nextfree = Worksheets("Data").Range("A1:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
         If Nextfree > 10 Then
         Worksheets("Data").Range("A2:D20").Copy Worksheets("Data").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Where do you end up if you tap ctrl+end?

Comment: You have to delete the unused rows. Also, if you only need last 20 rows of data, you could simply delete the first (n - 20) rows... If you're able to do that, you don't need to use copy/past commands on your code.

Comment: Try to `Cut` and paste instead of `Copy` and paste. With the copy action you aren't reducing the number of rows.

Comment: It appears to be solved now Variatus. Using Cut instead of copy seems to have done the trick.
I Am still wondering where excel puts the massive amounts of data when using the copy method.

Comment: It goes into the pool of dark energy :-)